# Вывод отдельных записей по произвольному полю

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

У записи есть произвольное поле с именем **gender** и со значением **male**.

Это поле имеет только одна запись, так почему выводит и другие записи, у которых значение не такое?

```
$arr = [
    'cat' => $id,
    'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'gender',
            'value' => 'male'
        ),
    ];

   $recent = new WP_Query($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Короче, фиг знает, как этот вордпресс работает, но после того, как добавил 'meta_key' => 'gender', то заработало.

```
$arr = [
                'cat' => 8,
                'meta_key' => 'gender',
                'meta_query' => array(
                        'key' => 'gender',
                        'value' => $gender
                    ),


            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [
    'cat' => $id,
    'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'gender',
            'value' => 'male',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    ];

   $recent = new WP_Query($arr);
```

Забыл compare.